# Google play store showing error "upload failed" while uploading new signed apk

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api, google-developers-console

[image: Play store error message]

Problems faced:

1. google play store asking to use different version code then 1 
   but I am already uploading new apk with version code 2
2. play store asking for privacy policy for READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_CONTACTS whereas I have removed these permissions from my updated apk

Please help.?

Comment: Post your gradle code also or manifest file(in case of eclipse)

Comment: error shown clear solution you just need to change version code in gradle (app)

Comment: Have you confirmed apk that you uploaded is new one itself.
1) Have you changed the version code and name
2) Are you using this READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_CONTACTS as run time  permission?

Comment: No I have removed all run time permission as well in my new apk with verson code 2 that i am trying to upload

Comment: Google has announced new policy if you are using  READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_CONTACTS then you have to define your privacy policy URL.....check this https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/privacy-policy-guide#why_we_require_a_privacy_policy

Comment: But I dont have these permitions in my new apk neither in manifest nor programitically

Comment: Is it because of Google Cloud Messaging and Google Analytics used in app that I am getting this message to include privacy policy.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already changed the version code and version name from gradle (Module Level) file
Then you need to build again release APK  and then try to upload it

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the version of the app in Android Studio. You have already uploaded an apk file with version code 1.

Please refer to below screenshot.
[image]

If you are still facing same issues, please try to clean and build the app once again and try to upload.

Comment: Sir I have already change my verson code to 2 in my gradle file

Comment: Yes, for that I mentioned that if you have already changed the version, then please try to CLEAN and BUILD your project and generate apk once again and try to upload it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Extracted Menifest File]

I have already changed version code to 2 and version name to 1.1.0

This is the extracted manifest of apk I am uploading.

Comment: Why did you post this as an answer? This is more information about the question. Please update your question.

Comment: sir I have already mentioned in question that i am getting error while uploading apk of version code 2